# unresolved reference for render_template

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pycharm, anaconda

hey everyone I'm new to the world of python and I have a problem that I can't find the answer. I'm using paycharm and i've installed anaconda that contains Flask of corse.
This is the code I wrote

[python code using paycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELPoW.png)

The error I get is "unresolved reference 'render_template' ".
I must mention that I already use anaconda"s interpretter.

Any ideas please ?

Comment: try changing `from flask import Flask` to `from flask import Flask, render_template`

Comment: It worked perfectly ! sorry for this beginers qustion and thank you .

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to import Flask and render_template. You can do this by putting **from flask import Flask,render_template**